# jquery - How to get xml data

Tags: xml, jquery

Im a total noob to html, css, javascript, and programming altogether. Please bear with me.

Im trying to populate my table using jquery. The data will be coming from an xml file.

**`football_player.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<football_player>
  <name>Cristiano Ronaldo</name>
  <club>Real Madrid</club>
  <number>7</number>
  <country>Portugal </country>

  <name>Fernando Torres </name>
  <club>Chelsea </club>
  <number>9</number>
  <country>Spain</country>

  <name>Iker Casillas</name>
  <club>Real Madrid </club>
  <number>1</number>
  <country>Spain</country>

  <name>David Beckham</name>
  <club>Los Angeles Galaxy</club>
  <number>23</number>
  <country>England</country>
</football_player>
```

My html table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Club</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
  </tfoot>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

My javascript/jquery script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "football_player.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find("football_player").each(function () {
        $("table tbody").append("<tr>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("name").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("club").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("number").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("country").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("</tr>");           
      });
    }
  });
});
```

I swear Im really a noob. I don't have any idea of what Im doing. Please help. I really want to learn. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @zerkms An elaboration wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: The data from the file is available in the variable `xml` within the function.

Comment: I updated my code. Please take a look. Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <RecentBooks>
     <Book>
      <Title>My Cool Book Title</Title>
    <Description>The my cool book is possibly the best cool book in that any developer could use to     be a great web designer.</Description>
    <Date>12/1/2010</Date>
    </Book>
    <Book>
     <Title>Another PHP book</Title>
    <Description>Learn everything about PHP with 'Another PHP book,' your ultimate guide to the ins and outs of PHP.</Description>
    <Date>4/1/2010</Date>
    </Book>
    <Book>
    <Title>jQuery Techniques</Title>
    <Description>jQuery techniques runs you through real life examples of jQuery from beginner to expert</Description>
     <Date>6/2/2010</Date>
     </Book>
     <Book>
    <Title>MySQL Database Book</Title>
    <Description>Brush up your knowledge with the best MySQL database book on the market.          </Description>
    <Date>14/2/2010</Date>
    </Book>
  </RecentBooks>
```

And the HTML & jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "books.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: xmlParser
  });
});
 
function xmlParser(xml) {
  $('#load').fadeOut();
 
  $(xml).find("Book").each(function () {
    $(".main").append('<div class="book"><div class="title">' + $(this).find("Title").text() + '</div><div class="description">' + $(this).find("Description").text() + '</div><div class="date">Published ' + $(this).find("Date").text() + '</div></div>');
    $(".book").fadeIn(1000);
  });
}

<div class="main">
  <div align="center" class="loader"><img src="loader.gif" id="load" width="16" height="11"   align="absmiddle"/></div>
</div>
 
<div class="clear"></div>
```

you can go through the example and you will get idea about the same

Answer (score 6):

I was in similar problem, where I was fetching XML data using HTTP GET and then parsing. Taking your example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "football_player.xml",
    ->dataType: "text",
    success: function(xml) {
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xml, "text/xml");
        var json = ->getJson(xmlDoc);
        for(var i =0; i< json[0].football_player.length;i++) {
            var player = json[0].football_player[i];
            $("table tbody").append("<tr>");
            $("table tbody").append("<td>" + ->player.name + "</td>");
            $("table tbody").append("<td>" + ->player.club + "</td>");
            $("table tbody").append("<td>" + ->player.number + "</td>");
            $("table tbody").append("<td>" + ->player.country + "</td>");
            $("table tbody").append("</tr>");
        }
    }
});
```

Three things to notice (->):

1. `dataType: "text"` I made http request with data type as TEXT rather than XML, so that I get xml data as a string data type.
2. `getJson(xmlDoc)` method: I wrote a small function to convert XML to Javascript object (JSON). There are other small utilities available to do the same.
3. `player.name`: due to this conversion, you can use XML content as javascript objects and thus easier to parse and read.

I am pasting `getJson()` function below (its not tested, I made it for a POC, but worked for me):

```
function getJson(xmlDoc) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < xmlDoc.children.length; i++) {
        var child = xmlDoc.children[i];
        if (result[child.tagName] === undefined) {
            result[child.tagName] = [];
        }

        var nodeJson = getJsonFromNode(xmlDoc.children[i]);
        result[child.tagName].push(nodeJson);
    }

    return result;
}

function getJsonFromNode(node) {
    var nodeJson = {};
    // for attributes
    for (var i = 0; i < node.attributes.length; i++) {
        var att = node.attributes[i];
        nodeJson[att.localName] = att.value;
    }

    // for child nodes
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
        var child = node.children[i];
        if (nodeJson[child.tagName] === undefined) {
            nodeJson[child.tagName] = [];
        }
        var result = getJsonFromNode(node.children[i]);
        nodeJson[child.tagName].push(result);
    }

    return nodeJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use `XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4` as `$.ajax` need [`setTimeout() method`](https://technotip.com/2199/reading-xml-file-using-jquery-ajax-method/) to get the response.

```
function reportStatus() {
  if (oXHR.readyState == 4) getXML(this.responseXML);
}

function getXML(xml) {
      $(xml).find("football_player").each(function () {
        $("table tbody").append("<tr>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("name").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("club").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("number").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("<td>" + $(this).find("country").text() + "</td>");
        $("table tbody").append("</tr>");           
      });
}

var oXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
oXHR.onreadystatechange = reportStatus;
oXHR.open("GET", "football_player.xml", true);
oXHR.send();
```

You may read more how this [code run](https://www.encodedna.com/javascript/practice-ground/default.htm?pg=extract_data_from_xml_file_using_javascript) as shown below:

[image: Extract XML Data using JavaScript]