# Store data from HTML to XML file

Tags: html, xml

Hello im trying to learn about XML , XML is media for store data but HTML media for display data, how can I store data from HTML to XML ?

Because i'd like to build some quiz maker that build up into HTML and store in XML, any tutorial/references for this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very open ended, so it's hard to answer. One way is to post data from your html based website to your server and store it as xml.
However, it all depends on how you intend to use it.

Answer (score 1):

XML is just a fancy way to store data for your application.  It's a standard which means that you can easily export data from one application into another.  If you are interested in this, take a look at this page: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp

You will need to use html and javascript to build a quiz.  If you want you can make your quiz load questions and answers from XML.

HTML is a specialized language written in XML to describe how a webpage renders.  HTML is valid XML however they very different things.

Comment: okay i'v been read the link that, but im very newbie for XML. is there any link for some example code? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean "How can I load data stored in XML to html website". The simplest answer I can think of right now would be using jquery/javascript.

http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811511/jquery-how-to-get-xml-data
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113188/convert-xml-to-html-using-jquery-javascript

Comment: no, I mean store data to XML from HTML , but thanks for the links :)